# can you run sql server 2005 and sql server 2008 r2 in mirror mode?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, mirroring

Must all db servers be running the exact same version to enable mirroring without a witness server? How about with a witness server in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partners must be the same edition and the same version.

[Please see BOL's reference on Database Mirroring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> For a new mirroring session to be established, the partners and the witness, if any, must be running on the same version of SQL Server.

> Since SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 1 (SP1), database mirroring partners and witnesses have been supported by Standard and Enterprise Edition. But the partners must use the same edition, and asynchronous database mirroring (high-performance mode) is supported only by Enterprise Edition. Witnesses are also supported by Workgroup Edition and Express Edition.